# Отловить завершение ajax-запроса

Tags: ajax, javascript

Всем привет.

Собственно вопрос: как отловить завершение AXAX-запроса? Т.е. есть функция, вида

```
lib.someFunc(...);
```

Она используется как черный ящик, и внутри нее есть AJAX-запросы. Дело в том, что у нее нет никаких коллбэков для отлова завершения запросов.

Можно ли как-то на нативном JS проверить, завершены ли запросы к определенной странице, либо просто получить ответ вида "все запросы завершены"?

Буду благодарен за любую помощь. Спасибо.

Comment: Конечно, возвращайте «Обещание».

Comment: @altvirus, 

1. Грузимся перед библиотекой.
2. Подменяем оригинальный xhr на прокси, которая пропускает через себя все нативные методы, внутри логируем что хотим и как хотим.
3. Никогда больше так не делаем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promise поможет.
http://habrahabr.ru/post/209662/

Comment: promise поможет только в случае, если у меня есть доступы к xhr. А у меня только вызовы методов либы, в которых происходит очередь ajax запросов. Вот в таком случае как быть?

Answer (score 0):

В jquery есть обработчики ajax событий. http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

Comment: @Павел, разве это не местечковый только-jQuery глобальный обработчик? Т.е. сторонняя библиотека, выполняющая ajax-запрос, не дёрнет эти события.

Comment: По моему он работает, для всех запросов. Нужно проверять.